# Validating an account number using TCP Socket programming in Java

Tags: java

I am kind of new to socket programming.That being said,I am not new to jAVA.I got a question.I need to write a program where I can use a client to provide an account number so that the server can retrieve information using that account number (of a bank). My question: Can I put a few accounts in a hashmap or something and write a method inside the server to only fetch my account (if provided in the hashmap).In other words,no code needed.I will write that myself.Only trying to find an approach?

Comment: You can do whatever you want if it suits your needs. I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. What are you afraid of?

Comment: You should look at remote method invocation https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/

Comment: Sockets don't validate account numbers. Sockets might *transport* account numbers. Your question is confused,

Comment: Ok.sorry for the confusion.Is there a way I can validate any data from the client using my server program?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like *Remote Method Invocation* (RMI) would suit your needs. `HashMap` implements `Serializable`, so you would be able to send it directly to the server.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/overview.html

Comment: Well...Java RMI is my next assignment approach...For now,only TCP Sockets :)

Comment: Well, then you will have to send the raw data. XML or JSON would be well suited for the structure of map data.